# Devise modules on RoR: created view not requested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, module, devise

I'm new with RoR and devise framework.

I want only sign in page for Admin role.
I've executed:

```
rails g devise Admin
```

Then in admin.rb model i've only this modules:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable 

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

and edited properly the migration file.

Why devise has created the sign_up page too?
I've verified that if i try to sign up a user, that doesn't work...but i don't want that page.
How can i achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Devise to only allow routes for sessions, which should only allow logging in and out rather than creating new users.

Change the call to 'devise_for' in /config/routes.rb to something like;

```
devise_for :users, :only => :sessions
```

Check out the following page for more information on Devise routing;

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#devise_for-instance_method

Comment: Ok...but why Devise has generater that routes if i have enabled only database_authenticatable, :rememberable  module?

Comment: Routes and modules on a class are two different things.